# Need to pass a data from a json response to the subsequent request's Post Body data however it is not working, something is going wrong

Tags: jmeter

I need to pass a data from a json response to the subsequent request's Post Body data however it is not working, something is going wrong.

First request returns the JSON in response body which looks like this:

```
"accessToken":[{"idToken":"eyJ05C3RU","token":"159c82d30ec3123e873ab989cc"}]
0000000
```

I have to extract 'accessToken' value to pass it to the next request's post bodydata (not under parameter tab of the request, it has to pass to BodyData tab of the next request)

I have created to JSON path extractors for the first request where getting response data with these values.
1JSON path extractor: `$..accessToken[0].idToken`

passed this in json path expression:$..accessToken[0].idToken

in the request of next request: `{  "idtoken": ${idToken}}`

[image: Description]

view results in tree:
shows post data as request:

```
POST data:{  "idtoken": ${idToken}}
```

response data:

> omething broke!SyntaxError: Unexpected token $

```
at `Object.parse (native)`
```

Please help to resolve the issue. it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I am able to overcome my  issue by using JSON path expression extractor in the next request body as "idtoken": "${idToken_1}".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your JSON Path expression is wrong or response isn't valid JSON.

You can fall back to [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) which is not that handy, but will work for any text response, the relevant configuration would be:

- Apply to: same as for JSON Path extractor
- Reference name: `idToken`
- Regular Expression: `"idToken"\s?:\s?"(.+?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expressions Demo]

Reference material:

- [JSON Path Getting Started](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#getting-started) - if you want to continue with the JSON Path Extractor (double check that your response is a valid JSON using i.e. http://jsonlint.com/)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) - if you would like to go the regular expressions way

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However it is not working with RegExpression, able to fetch idToken value using JSON Path extractor. Used JSON path extractor expression: $..idToken , able to fetch idToken in the request bodydata but showing as "idToken": ["eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLIUzI1NiJ9.eyJXFw0OvBjJn-FRyJJI"]
It is showing with extra [] brackets, may be due to this it response is failing. Please suggest to remove these []

Comment: According to [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) article all you need to do is amending your JSON Path expression to look like ` $..idToken[0]`. With regards to Regular Expressions approach, it should be working as it evidenced by the above screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am able to remove brackets[] using "idToken": ${idToken_1} in the next request bodydata. Now the problem is it remove "" (double quotes), without double quotes getting the idToken value passed to the request. Please help.

Comment: I am able to get idToken in double quotes as well by using "idToken": "${idToken_1}". However the request response shows TOKEN not present in request. When used DebugSampler, getting two idTokens one with [] and other one without "". Is due to this getting 'token not present' (getting two values in debug sampler)